# Apply registry mod for UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, registry, text-to-speech

Is there anyway to apply registry mod on uwp applications? I'm using a registry mod for Eva TTS voice and I'm going to migrate from wpf to uwp. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the global registry from a UWP app. That would violate the app isolation model, as such modification would have system wide impact.

What is it that you really want to accomplish? Maybe there is a better to do it.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Yeah, But  Is there a way to import voices with application scope?It will be better.

Comment: I would suggest to ask a new question about this. Not sure it if such API exists today.